# Is there a music player for iOS with controls?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, mpmovieplayer

Is there a music player that has playback controls built in (like MPMoviePlayer) but for audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be relatively simple to implement custom controls for `AVAudioPlayer` located in the `AVFoundation` framework. It has pre-made methods for play, pause, and stop, and `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag` to handle playlists. You should give it a look.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you go with MPMoviePlayerController, for the audio files also? There you can play with the controls, view, frame etc.

Comment: Is it also possible to control it from different view controllers? The music must not stop while navigating? Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245399/is-there-a-music-player-for-ios-with-controls

Comment: I guess you can use the property - Required Background Modes with value - App plays audio. And you must ensure that your view-movie player is not getting deallocated/released. Hope this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple provide a example 'avTouch' that can be use as reference